# code compilation issues

Tags: compiling, gcc, make

I am working on a project related to jet physics.

For that, I am using a Linux terminal in my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I use libraries of Pythia, Fastjet and fastjet-contrib in my code.

When I recently used a library of `fastjet-contrib` in my code, I faced the error given below during compilation even though the same code got compiled in a different system that has Mac OS.

All the software versions and makefile on both of the systems are the same.

```
undefined reference to `vtable for fastjet::Recluster'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/oem/test/rivet/local/lib/libRecursiveTools.a(RecursiveSymmetryCutBase.o): in function `fastjet::Recluster::~Recluster()':
RecursiveSymmetryCutBase.cc:(.text._ZN7fastjet9ReclusterD2Ev[_ZN7fastjet9ReclusterD5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for fastjet::Recluster'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: * [makefile:2: tutorial1] Error 1
```

Comment: see http://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#vtables  "The solution is to ensure that all virtual methods that are not pure are defined. Note that a destructor must be defined even if it is declared pure-virtual [class.dtor]/7."

Comment: Here is a very detailed rundown on it https://stackoverflow.com/a/57504289  Top answer includes my previous comment ;)